# Rewrite one url parameter and leave other

Tags: nginx, url, url-rewriting

We change referral links query parameter and want to keep previous version of url.
In abstract variation I need that

```
/example?id=partner1&arg1=a&arg2=b
/?id=partner1&arg1=a&arg2=b
```

rewrite to

```
/example?rs=partners_partner1&arg1=a&arg2=b
/?rs=partners_partner1&arg1=a&arg2=b
```

```
id=partner1 -> rs=partners_partner1
```

How we can do this across nginx?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with the `rewrite` nginx directive since it works with so-called *normalized* URI which doesn't include the query string. Instead you need to alter the `$args` nginx internal variable:

```
if ($args ~ (^|.*&)id=([^&]*)($|&.*)) {
    set $args $1rs=partners_$2$3;
}
```

Put this block **outside** any of the `location` blocks.

Comment: thanks, that example didn't work. but works after I added '&' between $3 and $4 in "set" line. works perfectly

Comment: Sorry, my first regex was really broken and this could be solved with a more simple regex, check the updated answer.